# 07S01 invalid use of default parameter odbc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc, optional-parameters

I'm getting a strange error using OdbcConnection calling this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dba].[sp_webapi_document_post]( 
     @ai_codice_profilo VARCHAR(255)
    ,@ai_id_sog_commerciale INT
    ,@ai_num_documento VARCHAR(255)
    ,@ai_data_documento DATETIME
    ,@ai_id_documento_origine INT
    ,@ai_id_destinazione INT 
    ,@ai_id_lingua INT
    ,@ai_id_con_pagamento INT 
    ,@ai_note_intestazione VARCHAR(6400)
)
AS
BEGIN
...
SELECT * FROM dba.documento WHERE id_documento = <last inserted id>
```

With this SQL:

```
    EXEC 
        dba.sp_webapi_document_post
             @ai_codice_profilo = @p_codice_profilo
            ,@ai_id_sog_commerciale = @p_id_sog_commerciale
            ,@ai_num_documento = @p_num_documento
            ,@ai_data_documento = @p_data_documento
            ,@ai_id_documento_origine = @p_id_documento_origine
            ,@ai_id_destinazione = @p_id_destinazione
            ,@ai_id_lingua = @p_id_lingua
            ,@ai_id_con_pagamento = @p_id_con_pagamento
            ,@ai_note_intestazione = @p_note_intestazione
```

After calling ConvertToOdbcSql() method the SQL become:

```
    EXEC 
        dba.sp_webapi_document_post
             @ai_codice_profilo =  ? 
            ,@ai_id_sog_commerciale =  ? 
            ,@ai_num_documento =  ? 
            ,@ai_data_documento =  ? 
            ,@ai_id_documento_origine =  ? 
            ,@ai_id_destinazione =  ? 
            ,@ai_id_lingua =  ? 
            ,@ai_id_con_pagamento =  ? 
            ,@ai_note_intestazione =  ?
```

With this connection:

Connection string:

```
<add name="ImpresaConnection" connectionString="Dsn=felici;uid=sa;pwd=*secret*;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.OdbcClient"/>
```

And this C# code:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(DbConnectionString);
conn.Open();
String sql = InsertSql;
String outputSql = null;
List<string> orderedParamList = null;
// This function removes *correctly* @p_ parameters raplacing them with ? 
// and saving then into a ordered list user later by AddWithValue
OdbcSqlMappingUtils.ConvertToOdbcSql(sql, DataObjectMap, out outputSql, out orderedParamList);
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(outputSql, conn);
foreach (String param in orderedParamList)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, value.GetType().GetProperty(DataObjectMap[param]).GetValue(value, null));
}
OdbcDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
List<Document> list = MappingUtils.ReaderToList<Document>(r);
r.Close();
conn.Close();
return list.FirstOrDefault() ?? null;
```

And I Obtain a System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException with this message:
07S01 invalid use of default parameter odbc

Comment: Set a breakpoint before you execute the procedure command and verify that you have supplied a value for every parameter that the procedure is expecting.

Comment: The function ConvertToOdbcSql() checks if every parameter has a relative entry into DataObjectMap (dictionary of parameters) if that procedure find a @p_ parameter without a parameter it raise an exception...
>>> But I set some null values <<<